# No app want to opened?

Tags: 22.04, firefox, software-center

I am working on Ubuntu 22.04 from 3 months, almost all the applications among them Firefox, Visual Studio, app center... won't be opened just a few of them like chrome that works fine. I need help since all of my work is in my laptop.

When I open Firefox, It won't be lunched, and I tried to open it from the terminal, I face the following message:

```
cannot perform operation: mount --rbind /dev/tmp/snap.rootfs_wq9l51//dev: No such file or directory
```

when I tried `sudo snap refresh` it outputs

```
notion-snap-reborn 1.0.28 from Maxime (sunshio) refreshed
```

and the output of the command `snap list -all` is

```
    Name                       Version           Rev    Tracking         Publisher               Notes
bare                       1.0               5      latest/stable    canonical✓              base
code                       0ee08df0          148    latest/stable    vscode✓                 classic
code                       -                 147    latest/stable    vscode✓                 disabled,broken
core18                     -                 2796   latest/stable    canonical✓              disabled,broken
core18                     -                 2812   latest/stable    canonical✓              broken
core20                     -                 2015   latest/stable    canonical✓              disabled,broken
core20                     -                 2105   latest/stable    canonical✓              broken
core22                     20230801          864    latest/stable    canonical✓              base,disabled
core22                     -                 1033   latest/stable    canonical✓              broken
discord                    0.0.39            172    latest/stable    snapcrafters✪           -
discord                    -                 171    latest/stable    snapcrafters✪           disabled,broken
figma-linux                0.11.1            178    latest/stable    youdonthavepermissiony  -
firefox                    121.0-1.1         3600   latest/stable    mozilla✓                -
firefox                    120.0.1-1         3506   latest/stable    mozilla✓                disabled
gnome-3-28-1804            -                 198    latest/stable    canonical✓              broken
gnome-3-38-2004            0+git.efb213a     143    latest/stable/…  canonical✓              -
gnome-42-2204              0+git.ff35a85     120    latest/stable/…  canonical✓              disabled
gnome-42-2204              0+git.ff35a85     141    latest/stable/…  canonical✓              -
gtk-common-themes          0.1-81-g442e511   1535   latest/stable/…  canonical✓              -
jupyter                    1.0.0             6      latest/stable    projectjupyter✓         -
mesa-core22                23.0.4            231    latest/stable    canonical✓              -
notion-snap-reborn         1.0.27            26     latest/stable    sunshio                 -
notion-snap-reborn         -                 25     latest/stable    sunshio                 disabled,broken
obsidian                   1.4.16            21     latest/stable    obsidianmd              disabled,classic
obsidian                   1.5.3             22     latest/stable    obsidianmd              classic
qt5-core20                 20.04             15     latest/stable    keshavnrj✪              -
snap-store                 41.3-71-g709398e  959    latest/stable/…  canonical✓              disabled
snap-store                 0+git.e118b05     1046   latest/stable/…  canonical✓              -
snapd                      2.60.4            20290  latest/stable    canonical✓              snapd
snapd                      -                 19457  latest/stable    canonical✓              disabled,broken
snapd-desktop-integration  0.9               83     latest/stable/…  canonical✓              -
telegram-desktop           4.12.2            5305   latest/stable    telegram-desktop✓       -
telegram-desktop           -                 5248   latest/stable    telegram-desktop✓       disabled,broken
utube                      2.1               55     latest/stable    keshavnrj✪              -
warzone2100-videos         -                 3      latest/stable    warzone-2100-project    broken
zoom-client                5.16.6.382        218    latest/stable    ogra  

              -
```

Comment: Please add to your question which error message(s) occur. Best way to see them all is to open a terminal and open the application from there, e.g by calling `firefox` from the terminal.

Comment: what do you mean by open? try to open it in terminal as @noisefloor said and if there is any errors, edit the post and post it.

Comment: Please run `sudo snap refresh` and then `snap list --all`. Please add the output of the latter to your question,

Comment: Ok, there is certainly something wrong with your snaps. Multiple snaps are broken, which shouldn't be the case. The root-cause for this is hard to tell remotely.
You *could* remove all broken snaps completely and re-install. I never had to do that myself so I cannot tell if there is any risk which comes with it. However, in case you decide to do so you should certainly backup all files which you created yourself using one of these programs (if you created any).